# Updating JSON field of Eloquent model

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, model, eloquent

So, I have a JSON field in my database. When I access it on my model object, I get a string, so I have to decode it myself. Is it possible to access it like an object? I could define an accessor, but in that case I wouldn't be able to change it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Attribute Casting`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting).

Let's assume that in your User model you have an `options` attribute of type `Json` so what you can do is adding in your User Model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'options' => 'array',
];
```

And simply if you want to edit this field you can just do it like so :

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

$options = $user->options;

$options['key'] = 'value';

$user->options = $options;

$user->save();
```